# What does "variable = ." (variable = dot) mean in Oracle SQL/SAS?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, sas

I am converting a SAS script to Python, where the SAS script was interfacing with an Oracle database, and the Python will be interfacing with a PostgreSQL database. In the SAS code, I found this statement:

```
proc sql noprint;
create table table_name as
  select distinct wtn
    from another_table
   where account = .
;
```

What does "where account = ." mean in Oracle? Or is it not an Oracle SQL thing, and instead is a SAS thing? Or is it available in all forms of SQL?

Further, if it is SAS and/or Oracle specific, what would I use in PostgreSQL in its place?

Comment: it is a SAS SQL thing.use account=whatevervalue in others.

Comment: @vkp The dot doesn't get defined somewhere. How do I know what to compare account to?

Comment: does the code run as-is in sas?

Comment: @vkp I am unable to test it, because I was just handed the script and told to convert it. I'm assuming it runs, and has been running for at least the last 8 years or so.

Comment: from what i can guess,it should have been a variable defined in the program and you are missing that info.

Comment: Dot is missing numeric in SAS (so effectively same as NULL).  From your latest few questions - perhaps you should go read a few papers on basic SAS?  You can download SAS University Edition, which runs in a VM and lets you actually run SAS and test things out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In SAS Missing values for numeric variables (including date variables) appear as a period. SAS treats numeric nulls as equal to “the lowest possible number” (essentially negative infinity) when sorting a numeric field.

SAS datasets will have a period as a value for missing data.  When you export the data as CSV using proc export, I believe it will create a null value.  To really answer your question you will need to know how the ETL from sasdata set to the current database was done.

I expect your data has been normalized for your database. Because of this I think you should use "IS NULL" in place of a "varname = '.' " .  See below:

```
create table table_name as
select distinct wtn
from another_table
  where account is NULL
;
```

In addition SAS Missing values for character variables appear as blanks.  Missing values are set like this for character:  if name="none" then name=' '.